# Python Pandas: Merge doesnt handle NaN correctly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I'm working with a large dataset. The following example is similar to my own data:

Example:

- We count how many trees have grown in each area each year ("t-count").
- Each year new trees are planted and we know the year where those trees will finally grow ("year_of_growth").
- The goal is to create a new column ("seed_result") which contains the number of trees which resulted from the seeds of that year.
- If the "year_of_growth" is unknown (= NaN), no "seed_result" can be calculated

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ids = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3]
year = [2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,1990,1991,1992,1993,1994,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004]
y1 = [2002,2002,2004,2004,np.NaN,1991,1992,1993,np.NaN,np.NaN,2002,2002,2003,2004,np.NaN]
count = [10,14,20,11,8,
        20,22,20,25,18,
        30,19,15,10,26]

dictt1 ={"area_id":ids,"year":year,"t-count": count,"year_of_growth":y1}
dft1 = pd.DataFrame(dictt1)

print(dft1)
    area_id  year  t-count  year_of_growth
0         1  2000       10          2002.0
1         1  2001       14          2002.0
2         1  2002       20          2004.0
3         1  2003       11          2004.0
4         1  2004        8             NaN
5         2  1990       20          1991.0
6         2  1991       22          1992.0
7         2  1992       20          1993.0
8         2  1993       25             NaN
9         2  1994       18             NaN
10        3  2000       30          2002.0
11        3  2001       19          2002.0
12        3  2002       15          2003.0
13        3  2003       10          2004.0
14        3  2004       26             NaN
```

The result should look like this:

```
    area_id  year  t-count  year_of_growth  seed_result
0         1  2000       10          2002.0         20.0
1         1  2001       14          2002.0         20.0
2         1  2002       20          2004.0          8.0
3         1  2003       11          2004.0          8.0
4         1  2004        8             NaN          NaN
5         2  1990       20          1991.0         22.0
6         2  1991       22          1992.0         20.0
7         2  1992       20          1993.0         25.0
8         2  1993       25             NaN          NaN
9         2  1994       18             NaN          NaN
10        3  2000       30          2002.0         15.0
11        3  2001       19          2002.0         15.0
12        3  2002       15          2003.0         10.0
13        3  2003       10          2004.0         26.0
14        3  2004       26             NaN          NaN
```

My own approach to this problem has been to use the "merge-function". This seems to work for the first few datapoints, but then fails at the first "NaN"-value in the "year_of_growth"-column. The following problems arise:

- The result shows "seed_result"-values even when there are "NaN"-values in the "year_of_growth"-column
- After the first "NaN"-value in the "year_of_growth"-colum all consequent "seed_result"-values are wrong
- I tried simply using ".fillna()" to change the NaN-values to "-999" but that didnt change the result

My own approach looks like this:

```
dft1["seed_result"] = dft1.merge(dft1, left_on=["area_id","year"],
                                                  right_on=["area_id","year_of_growth"],
                                                  how="right")["t-count_x"]
print(dft1)
    area_id  year  t-count  year_of_growth  seed_result
0         1  2000       10          2002.0         20.0
1         1  2001       14          2002.0         20.0
2         1  2002       20          2004.0          8.0
3         1  2003       11          2004.0          8.0
4         1  2004        8             NaN         22.0
5         2  1990       20          1991.0         20.0
6         2  1991       22          1992.0         25.0
7         2  1992       20          1993.0         15.0
8         2  1993       25             NaN         15.0
9         2  1994       18             NaN         10.0
10        3  2000       30          2002.0         26.0
11        3  2001       19          2002.0          NaN
12        3  2002       15          2003.0          NaN
13        3  2003       10          2004.0          NaN
14        3  2004       26             NaN          NaN
```

I would be very thankful for any suggestion that leads to the right result! Please keep in mind that the real dataset is much larger than this one.

Comment: What is your pandas version? Tested in `1.1.1` and working correct your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jezreal Thank you for providing the solution!

Upgrading my version of pandas to 1.1.2 solved the issue.